Devtool modify recipe not working correctly in Kirkstone
Facing issue using devtool modify recipe in Yocto kirsktone.
Error Snippet:
devtool modify nginx
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
NOTE: Reconnecting to bitbake server...
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#1)...
Loading cache: 100% |##########################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 4296 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-22.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-mymachine-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "mymachine"
DISTRO               = "mymachine-distro"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "5.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa9 neon thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta
meta-poky            = "HEAD:d8d6d921fad14b82167d9f031d4fca06b5e01883"
meta-oe
meta-multimedia
meta-python
meta-webserver       = "HEAD:79a6f60dabad9e5b0e041efa91379447ef030482"
meta-freescale       = "HEAD:dfd01d7bdf87b6bda254780a35659975d2b2c66e"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "HEAD:1a6ea560015ecda5fff8eccaf5b1327f1bb6c57f"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:d5bbb487b2816dfc74984a78b67f7361ce404253"
meta-mymachine             = "HEAD:cbc60c9a70126002d1c021a5527e8c169fc88d7d"
workspace            = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
meta-networking      = "HEAD:79a6f60dabad9e5b0e041efa91379447ef030482"
meta-murata-wireless = "HEAD:c88c70e7d728f7b26583911ebe1bd0310b5e1ba0"
meta-scipy           = "HEAD:1d17ab020786bf4614907f5185dce4a928a2a762"

Initialising tasks: 100% |#####################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Sstate summary: Wanted 12 Local 12 Mirrors 0 Missed 0 Current 8 (100% match, 100% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 93 tasks of which 93 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
ERROR: Something went wrong with source extraction - the devtool-source class was not active or did not function correctly:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/build/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-mymachine-linux-gnueabi/nginx/1.20.1-r0/devtooltmp-a6t1d69v/initial_rev'

I checked the Yocto manuals but unable to determine as to why devtool modify is not working correctly. Is there some bbclass file that I am missing?
I can do devtool edit-recipe nginx and it takes me to the respective recipe for editing.
I can see that the workspace layer is clean and there are no open recipes present.
Similarly, devtool modify virtual/kernel also fails.
Checked bitbake-cookerdaemon.log but unable to determine any relevant information.
Can use devshell for it but I want to know why devtool modify recipe-name fails.
Misc:
Utilized manifest.xml - imx-5.15.71-2.2.1.xml
from https://github.com/nxp-imx/imx-manifest/tree/imx-linux-kirkstone
Added my machine specific layer.
Ubuntu 22.04LTS
